# How to trigger Dropdown of Datalist HTML using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="" class="customize-input clickDp" list="dpA1" id="dropdown-Account">
<span class="show-dropdown"><img src="images/click-dp.png"></span>
<datalist id="dpA1">
    <option value="1"/>
    <option value="2"/>
</datalist>
```

What I want is to show the dropdown once I click the span `.show-dropdown`.
So far here is my code:

```
$('.show-dropdown').on('click',function(){
   var e = $.Event("keydown");
   e.which = 40; // # Some key code value
   e.keyCode = 40
   $(".clickDp").trigger(e);
   //$(".clickDp").trigger('keyup', [{preventDefault:function(){},keyCode:40}]); })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this you wanted? Here i used select. May be this will help you.

```js
$('.show-dropdown').on('click',function(){

        var $target = $("#dpA1");
        var $clone = $target.clone().removeAttr('id');
        $clone.val($target.val()).css({
            overflow: "auto",
            position: 'absolute',
            'z-index': 999,
            left: $target.offset().left,
            top: $target.offset().top + $target.outerHeight(),
            width: $target.outerWidth()
        }).attr('size', $clone.find('option').length > 10 ? 10 : $clone.find('option').length).change(function() {
            $target.val($clone.val());
        }).on('click blur keypress',function(e) {
         if(e.type !== "keypress" || e.which === 13)
            $(this).remove();
        });
        $('body').append($clone);
        $clone.focus();

   
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eduardolundgren/jquery-simulate/master/jquery.simulate.js"></script>

<select id="dpA1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>



<span class="show-dropdown"><img src="images/click-dp.png"></span>
```

Comment: Is there a way to use only datalist?

Answer (score 0):

No solution involving triggering or simulating mouse clicks or key presses is going to work.

But if the dropdown button is absolutely positioned over the text area,
this trick does work:

```
$('.dropdown .arrow').on( 'mouseenter', function( e ) {
  $( e.target ).parent().find( 'input' )[0].focus();
  $(e.target ).addClass( 'no-click' );
});
  $('.dropdown').on( 'mouseleave', function( e ) {
  $('.dropdown .arrow').removeClass( 'no-click' );
});
```

Clicking a text input with a datalist will cause the menu to appear, but it takes two clicks because the first one just gives it the focus.

This makes the text input field steal focus as soon as you mouse over the arrow button and gives the arrow a 'no-click' class ( which you've defined in CSS as 'pointer-events:none;" ). So the first click goes right through it to the input field, and the menu shows up.